# Matriz en PL/ SQL

Tags: matrices, plsql

Tengo la siguiente pregunta:

Tengo tres columnas: el producto seleccionado por el cliente en el mes 1 y el producto seleccionado por el cliente en el mes 2 y el número de clientes que tienen esta disposición y quiero hacer una matriz de qué productos se mantienen y cuáles han cambiado, que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
            Producto 1 Mes 2    Producto 2 Mes 2 Producto 3 Mes 2
```

Producto 1 Mes 1     100                       2            40
Producto 2 Mes 1      40                      50            100
Producto 3 Mes 1     90                       0             200

Para no tener que hacerlo columna a columna, ¿hay alguna forma de que en SQL se ponga de forma en forma de matriz?

Gracias

Comment: no se ve bien la matriz..pero la idea es formar una matriz de tantas filas como productos haya en el mes 1 y columnas como productos haya en el mes 2

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver PL/SQL? ¿Cual base de datos usas? ¿Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Podiras utilizar la función concat que te ayuda a poner varias columnas en una 
CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )  aca hay un ejemplo

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'Happy ', 'Birthday ', 11, '/', '25' ) AS Result;
```

Este es el link donde puedes ver mas información
[link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)